# Searching a sorted array of floating point numbers

Tags: c++, arrays, search, boost

Is there an optimized function in any numerical library (MKL, Boost, GSL,..etc) that searches  a sorted array of floating point numbers for the closest match to a given float?
 Another function which will solve the same problem for me will generate a random sample from a custom discrete probability distribution.

Comment: [Binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) basically gives you that. It gives you 2 candidates (if the numbers is not in the list): One upper and one lower, just find which of them is closest

Comment: You can use [std::lower_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) from STL, which effectively implements a binary search, to find the two closest candidates, as @amit suggests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrapping comments (of me & @betabandido) into an answer:

You basically need to find 2 candidates, the closest "upper" element, and the closest "lower" element (assuming the element is not in the list). This can be achieved using [Binary Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) efficiently (`O(logN)`)

By using [std::lower_bound()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) you can get the higher element, and the lower is the element before it in the array.

Compare the two candidates - the one which is closest to the given float is your answer.

Comment: Does lower_bound work on arrays as well or only data structures such as vectors?

Comment: @Tarek That is the fine thing about the standard library algorithms, they work with nearly anything. Just use `std::begin(array)` and `std::end(array)` to get the iterator range or, if you don't have C++11 or the array is allocated dynamically (though I'd question that in the first place, but be it so), use `array` and `array+size` respecitively.